# Пересечения массивов С#, один для Rigidbody, другой для Overlap Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть два массива, один

```
Collider[] coldal = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radiusdal);
```

Второй

```
 Rigidbody[] rbs;

void Start() {
     rbs = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Rigidbody)) as Rigidbody[];


}
```

Надо найти в них пересечения, т.е. все Rigidbody, находящиеся в данный момент в OverlapSphere.

Пробовал без массива Rigidbody, но получается использование GetComponent в Update, что не лучшим образом сказывается на ресурсах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждого `collider` есть ссылка на `rigidbody` к которому он привязан [Collider.attachedRigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-attachedRigidbody.html). Так что все что надо это просто сопоставить два массива.